# Is conversion from EMC (*.ngc) to heidenhain (*.h) CNC code possible?

Tags: computer-aided-design, cnc

I have some gcode created with dmap2gcode. This and Meshcam are the only software I could find that could would take a large image and create the necessary gcode.

Now I would like to try cutting this on a different machine. This machine however is only connected to a SolidCam PC and cant be messed with. I know that it can produce Heidenhain gcode files which seem to be the closest format to what is used in the .ngc file.

Is there software which could translate the EMC gcode to Heidenhain gcode?

Sample .ngc

```
( Code generated by dmap2gcode-0.07.py widget )
( by Scorch - 2014 )
(Settings used in dmap2gcode when this file was created)
(=========================================================)
(dmap2gcode_set show_axis  1 )
(dmap2gcode_set invert     0 )
(dmap2gcode_set normalize  0 )
(dmap2gcode_set cuttop     1 )
(dmap2gcode_set cutperim     1 )
(dmap2gcode_set disable_arcs 0 )
(dmap2gcode_set yscale     127 )
(dmap2gcode_set toptol     -0.127 )
(dmap2gcode_set vangle     45 )
(dmap2gcode_set stepover   1.02 )
(dmap2gcode_set plFEED     254 )
(dmap2gcode_set z_safe      6.35 )
(dmap2gcode_set z_cut       -12.7 )
(dmap2gcode_set diatool    6.35 )
(dmap2gcode_set origin     Default )
(dmap2gcode_set tool       Ball )
(dmap2gcode_set units      mm )
(dmap2gcode_set plunge     simple )
(dmap2gcode_set feed       381 )
(dmap2gcode_set lace       None )
(dmap2gcode_set cangle     45.0 )
(dmap2gcode_set tolerance  0.0254 )
(dmap2gcode_set splitstep  0 )
(dmap2gcode_set gpre       "G17 G90 G64 P0.001 M3 S3000" )
(dmap2gcode_set gpost      "M5|M2" )
(dmap2gcode_set scanpat    "Rows" )
(dmap2gcode_set scandir    "Alternating" )
(dmap2gcode_set imagefile  x )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_TOOL     Ball )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_DIA      6.35 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_V_ANGLE  45 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_R_FEED   381 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_P_FEED   254 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_STEPOVER 1.02 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_DEPTH_PP 2.54 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_OFFSET   0.508 )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_SCANPAT  "Rows" )
(dmap2gcode_set ROUGH_SCANDIR  "Alternating" )
(=========================================================)
G17 G90 G64 P0.001 M3 S3000
G21
G91.1
G0 Z6.3500
F381.0000
G18
F254.0000
G0 X254.0000 Y127.0000
F381.0000
G1 Z-11.7156
 X248.1755 Z-11.7342
G2 X247.6719 Y127.0000 Z-11.7835 I0.0438 K-3.0451
G1 X245.5041 Z-11.7844
 X244.5407 Z-11.8400
 X242.7233 Z-11.8420
G2 X242.2197 Y127.0000 Z-11.7970 I-0.5310 K-3.1026
G1 X233.1107 Z-11.7978
 X231.2495 Z-11.7528
G2 X230.7240 Y127.0000 Z-11.7038 I-0.5473 K-3.0262
G1 X222.0310 Z-11.7541
 X220.6734 Z-11.7722
 X218.9655 Z-11.9030
 X218.1772 Z-11.9114
G2 X217.5860 Y127.0000 Z-11.9992 I0.2959 K-4.0213
G1 X215.1993 Z-12.1024
```

a sample from the .H file:

```
0 BEGIN PGM PLATTENP1 MM
1 BLK FORM 0.1 Z X+0.000 Y-500.000 Z-42.000
2 BLK FORM 0.2 X+500.000 Y+0.000 Z+0.000
3 ; TEIL-NAME    : PVC_UNTEN - KOPIE
4 ; PROGRAMM-NR. : 1
5 ; DATUM - ZEIT : 30-OCT-2015 - 11:13:10
6 ; ERSTELLT MIT SOLIDCAM
7 ; PP-STAND 2.0 VOM 28.10.2015
8 * VERWENDETE WERKZEUGE:
9 ; T19 SCHAFTFRÄSER D19.746
10 ; T12 SCHAFTFRÄSER D5.968
11 * WERKZEUGE/JOBS:
12 TOOL CALL 19 Z S7000
13 *     HSR-R-CONT-FERTIGMODELL
14 CYCL DEF 32.0 TOLERANZ
15 CYCL DEF 32.1 T0.05
16 CYCL DEF 32.2 HSC-MODE:0 TA3
17 L X+142.093 Y-142.093 R0 FMAX M3
18 L Z+16.000 FMAX
19 L Z+0.490 FMAX
20 CC X+140.696 Y-140.696
21 CP IPA+45.000 IZ-0.044 DR+ F3000
22 CC X+140.696 Y-140.696
23 CP IPA+90.000 IZ-0.087 DR+
24 CC X+140.696 Y-140.696
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much more, your best bet would be to switch your Heidenhain controller from Conversational Mode to G-Code mode(this is a setting in the controller) This way you can run g-code on the Heidenhain. You may want to more closely look at that code and make sure you clear all modal codes/offsets and run the program in single block mode if you're going to try it out.  Good luck!